# Postgresql: how statistics are collected in the histogram_bounds

Tags: postgresql

The documentation of Postgresql is the explanation that this histogram_bounds field in pg_stats.

> The histogram divides the range into equal frequency buckets, so all we have to do is locate the bucket that our value is in and count part of it and all of the ones before.

But I still can not understand how the algorithms based on this field. I would like to describe in more detail how ANALYZE puts value in this field.

Comment: The question isn't very clear.  But you'll likely find relevant answers here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats-details.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it may be useful for you (and for any person who would like to understand the process of statistics gathering) to investigate PostgreSQL source code of ANALYZE command ([here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/36f40ce2dc66f1a36d6a12f7a0352e1c5bf1063e/src/backend/commands/analyze.c#L2371)).

Particularly for the process of `histogram_bounds` field filling one should look at the code starting from the line 2709 ([here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/36f40ce2dc66f1a36d6a12f7a0352e1c5bf1063e/src/backend/commands/analyze.c#L2709)).